# How do I copy a file within a subdirectory into an adjoining subdirectory?

Tags: shell-script, cp, for

My hierarchy is MyPDB -(5rea,5res,5rez) in which each `5rea`, `5res`, .. contain a directory called `MD` which contains a file named `production_10ns.out`. I want to copy `production_10ns.out` from each `MD` subdirectory under `5rea`, `5res` etc. to another subdirectory `analysis` already present under each `5rea`, `5res` etc. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

I have tried

```
$ for production_10ns.out in /scratch/srnaik/MyPDB/*/MD
 do cp production_10ns.out /scratch/srnaik/MyPDB/*/analysis/
 done
```

Comment: Your directories `5rea`, `5res`, etc are missing.  You also need to `cd` into the directory from where you are copying, or specify the entire path to source file.

Comment: The main failure in your code is that you do want expand `*` to all possibilities in the `for` header but in the `for` body you need something that expands to just the one instance you are currently working on.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the hierarchy you are looking for

```
scratch/
└── srnaik
    └── MyPDB
        ├── 5rea
        │   ├── MD
        │   │   └── production_10ns.out
        │   └── analysis
        │       └── production_10ns.out
        ├── 5res
        │   ├── MD
        │   │   └── production_10ns.out
        │   └── analysis
        │       └── production_10ns.out
        └── 5rez
            ├── MD
            │   └── production_10ns.out
            └── analysis
                └── production_10ns.out
```

If so, this script would do the trick,

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /scratch/srnaik/MyPDB

for i in {a..z}; do
    [ -d "5re${i}" ] && cp 5re${i}/MD/production_10ns.out 5re${i}/analysis/
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your code:

1. Variables can not generally contain a dot (you use `production_10ns.out` as a variable name in the `for` loop).
2. You can't copy a file to several directories at once with `cp`, which you seem to be doing by using a globbing pattern as the destination path.

Instead, loop over all `production_10ns.out` files and copy them to their new location:

```sh
for pathname in /scratch/srnaik/MyPDB/*/MD/production_10ns.out; do
    cp "$pathname" "${pathname%/*}/../analysis"
done
```

Here, `"$pathname"` will be the absolute pathname to a `production_10ns.out` file in each iteration.

The expansion `${pathname%/*}` will remove the actual filename at the end of the pathname, so that if `$pathname` is `/scratch/srnaik/MyPDB/5rea/MD/production_10ns.out`, then `${pathname%/*}` would expand to `/scratch/srnaik/MyPDB/5rea/MD`.

You could also use `$( dirname "$pathname" )` in place of `${pathname%/*}`:

```sh
for pathname in /scratch/srnaik/MyPDB/*/MD/production_10ns.out; do
    cp "$pathname" "$( dirname "$pathname" )/../analysis"
done
```

The `../analysis` at the end of the destination path finds the sibling `analysis` directory.

Assuming that this directory exists, the `cp` command would copy the file into it.

To *make sure* that the destination directory exists, use

```sh
mypdb_dir=/scratch/srnaik/MyPDB

for pathname in "$mypdb_dir"/*/MD/production_10ns.out; do
    [ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue

    targetdir=$( dirname "$pathname" )/../analysis
    mkdir -p "$targetdir" || exit 1

    cp "$pathname" "$targetdir"
done
```

This would create the destination directory if it doesn't already exist, or it would exit the shell it failed to create the directory.

I'm also explicitly testing whether the file we're currently investigating actually exists and is a regular file first (with the `-f` test).  If the pattern that we iterate over does not match *any* files, it would remain unexpanded, and the test catches this scenario.

The extra variable `mypdb_dir` added is just to keep the code a bit tidier.